# resolve url/url.content not fetching the correct path for css and scripts after hosting in IIS6.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, url, iis-6, hosting

i have hosted my application on IIS 6.0 the view that i wanted to browse is getting fetched in the browser but the css and scripts are not being rendered .

```
<link href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Tree.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

in this way i have given the path.

Answer (score 2):

The `link` tag is properly defined. You are using the `Url.Content` method with a relative path from the site root which will correctly take into account the virtual directory which could be added when hosting under IIS.

I would recommend you looking at [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see why the path is not found and what response does the server send when the CSS is fetched. Is the file missing? Or is there some other status code returned?